# namespaces in class inheritance in php

Tags: php, class, inheritance, namespaces

I have been trying to undertand this with no light.

This is my scenario:

Files and folders:

```
---> Controller (dir)
------> baseController.php
------> extController.php
------> admin (dir)
---------> user.php
------> user (dir)
---------> user.php
```

Files content:

baseController.php

```
namespace controller;

class baseController
{
    .
    .....
    ....
 }
```

extController.php

```
namespace controller;

class extController extends baseController
{
    .
    .....
    ....
 }
```

admin\user.php

```
namespace controller\admin;

class user extends \controller\extController
{
    .
    .....
    ....
 }
```

user\user.php

```
namespace controller\user;

class user extends \controller\extController
{
    .
    .....
    ....
 }
```

If I call to a method in admin namespace user class I got:

Fatal error: Class 'controller\extController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxxxxxx_com\src\controller\admin\user.php on line 6

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You may add `use controller;` before class definition in admin\user.php

Comment: How are you autoloading these classes?

Comment: Did you include the classes?

Comment: You are right, I haven't included the extController when loading classes. Thanks so much.